# React/ Material-UI how to conditionally render a div with class styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am making a flashcard app using React and Material-UI.  The design for the flash card is a simple white box which will either render the front side of the card or the reverse side with 3 buttons to indicate proficiency.  The card uses a conditional rendering statement to determine which side to show.  The problem I am having is when I try to add a class to the div with the buttons in order to apply my material-ui styling.

Here is the render statement:

```
displayFlashcard = (deck) => {
    if(!this.state.flip){
      return this.state.front;
    } else {
      return (<div><p>{this.state.back}</p><div className={classes.responseButtons}><IconButton><ThumbDownAlt /></IconButton><IconButton><Lock /></IconButton><IconButton><ThumbUpAlt /></IconButton></div></div>)
    }
  }
```

The error I get says that classes is not defined.  I have classes defined in my render,

```
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props
    return (
```

and use it a few times on divs in the return.  How can I add classes to the divs I want to conditionally render when they are declared outside of the render method?

Comment: `displayFlashcard` is a method inside the Component, right?

Comment: Correct, it is inside the component before the render method.

Comment: Then it looks like it is simply missing the full path of the object: `this.props.classes`. Does this solve it?